# On Duplicate Key Update won't update, but throws an error for duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a two-column primary key `(key1,key2)`.

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO mytable (key1, key2, val1, val2) 
VALUES (:k1, :k2, :v1, :v2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1 = val1 + :v1, val2 = val2 + :v2
```

Now when I insert a row with a duplicate key, I get this error message:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '157-433' for key
>   "PRIMARY" in ...

Why doesn't it just update the existing (157,433)-row?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't refer to the same placeholder multiple times in a query. MySQL has a built-in solution to this -- if you use `VALUES(colname)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause, it refers to the value that would have been stored in the column if it hadn't been a duplicate. So use:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (key1, key2, val1, val2)
VALUES (:k1, :k2, :v1, :v2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1 = val1 + VALUES(val1), val2 = val2 + VALUES(val2)
```

I'm not sure why it's causing an error about creating a duplicate entry, though.